# SQL, get any data between two days and specific time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to get any data that is between that time range of two days ago until yesterday.
Example: Retrieve any data between 3 PM two days ago and yesterday 3 PM. This query should work on the daily basis.

I am thinking something like but just don't know where to insert the time

```
select * from dbo.table where system_date between getdate()-2 and getdate()-1
```

Comment: Don't treat dates like a numerical value; it's a bad habit and doesn't work on the "new" data types (like `date` and `datetime2`). If you want to add/subtract a time period from a date (and time) value, use `DATEADD`. Also, with date and time values (and dates if I am honest), using `BETWEEN` isn't a good habit either; use `>=` and `<` logic for explicit boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)` to get the beginning of today's date, then use `DATEADD` to subtract 1 or 2 days, and add 15 hours.

I strongly suggest you use `>= AND <` on dates, rather than `BETWEEN`, otherwise you get "on the interval" issues.

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM dbo.[table] t
WHERE t.system_date >= DATEADD(hour, 15, DATEADD(day, -2, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)))
  AND t.system_date <  DATEADD(hour, 15, DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)));
```

Comment: I really can't wait for `DATE_BUCKET` for stuff like this.

Comment: Yeah well there is also `DATETRUNC`, I still don't get why they haven't made it (as well as other such functions) have a [monotonic constraint](https://explainextended.com/2010/02/19/things-sql-needs-sargability-of-monotonic-functions/), so that the compiler can infer the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select * 
from dbo.table 
where system_date between dateadd(day, datediff(day, 2, getdate()), '15:00:00') and dateadd(day, datediff(day, 1, getdate()), '15:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DATEADD` for subtracting dates. Your query will look like this.

```
select *
from table
where system_date between dateadd(day, -2, getdate()) and dateadd(day, -1, getdate())
```

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion. Including the time though would be the next challenge.